# Are there any side effects by using contentMode property in my custom scrollview inherited from UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiviewcontentmode

I want to use `contentMode` property on `MyScrollView` inherited from `UIScrollView`. 
Are there any effects to `MyScrollView` by using `contentMode` property?

Comment: What is the effect that you're after?

Comment: @slickdaddy
I'm just checking any side effects before using it for my own operation..

Comment: `contentMode` is not typically a property used on a scroll view, it's a property inherited from `UIView`. What is the purpose of using it in your case?

Comment: Oh, I use for viewForZooming(in: UIScrollView)'s contentView's contentMode. It seems to be a better approach to create a new property. Thanks!

Comment: Trial and error then. Try them all see how it effects your views. If it does nothing, don't add it.